# How to declare a Bignum with value 1 in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am working on a client side project, and which will communicate with server through SOAP.
And there are some APIs accept dynamic type parameters. But at the server side, it will check the parameter's type strictly, and Integer is totally incompliant with Long.
With this background, I want to send a request with a Long value 1, but in Ruby the type of variable is Fixnum all the time, and my request cannot pass the check. This issue doesn't exist in python, java and C++.
So who can give me a hand?

Thanks.
Johnny.

Answer (score 4):

The long num is automatically converted to `Bignum`:

```
11111111111111111111.class
# => Bignum
```

The excerpt from the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Bignum.html):

> Bignum objects hold integers outside the range of Fixnum. Bignum objects are created automatically when integer calculations would otherwise overflow a Fixnum. When a calculation involving Bignum objects returns a result that will fit in a Fixnum, the result is automatically converted.

There is a boundary when numbers are over are automatically converted into `Bignum`. For [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) arch is `2**30-1`, for [x86-64](/questions/tagged/x86-64) arch is `2**62-1`:

```
(2**30-1).class
# => Fixnum 
(2**30).class
# => Bignum
```

And if you will try to get `Bignum` from `Bignum` below the boundary you will get the `Fixnum`:

```
bignum = (2**30)
# => 1073741824 
bignum.class
# => Bignum 
(bignum-1).class
# => Fixnum
```

And of course, if you subtract `Bignum` from `Bignum` to get `1`, **the number `1` will be of `Fixnum` always**:

```
((2**30+1)-(2**30)).class
# => Fixnum
```

According your question:

> Long value 1, but in Ruby the type of variable is Fixnum all the time

[long](/questions/tagged/long) number values, i.e. with bit count more than *32* for has no class similar to the `Fixnum` to handle it, so, you just need to show how you try to send a request through [soap](/questions/tagged/soap). I guess it can be do with the proper SOAP libraries for [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) written in [c](/questions/tagged/c), for example. Please see the [soap4r](https://rubygems.org/gems/soap4r) [gem](/questions/tagged/gem) for [ruby-1.8](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.8), or [soap4r-ruby1.9](http://rubygems.org/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9) [gem](/questions/tagged/gem) for [ruby-1.9](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.9), that could be used to try solving your issues.

Comment: Yes, of course, but how to handle the value 1.

Comment: In other words, it is impossible.

Comment: so I have to switch to other languages?

Comment: Because I need a Bignum with 1. Such as Long a = 1L in java, and a = long(1, 10) in python. The value is definitely 1, and its type must be like Long, Bignum in Ruby.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ up vote for good effort, but could you please fix first line of you answer 'bugnum' to bignum.

Comment: @yjt001 updated again with links to gems

Answer (score 2):

The promotion of `Fixnum`s to `Bignum`s (and the opposite) happens automatically and you shouldn't worry about it. There is no way to to declare `1` as a Bignum, it will always be a Fixnum.

Answer (score 2):

This is how Ruby's number types are organized:

- Numeric

  - Float
  - Ingeter

    - Fixnum
    - Bignum

(To be more prcise, threre are `Complex` and `Rational` as well, but forget about them for now...)

The distinction between `Fixnum` and `Bignum` is a kind of implementation details.  I think you should treat both of `Fixnum` and `Bignum` as `Integer`s.  Your SOAP protocol should send all integer data as `Integer`.

```
irb(main):013:0> 1.is_a? Fixnum
=> true
irb(main):014:0> (10**100).is_a? Fixnum
=> false
irb(main):015:0> (10**100).is_a? Integer
=> true
irb(main):016:0> 1.is_a? Integer
=> true
```

You will never want to distinguish 1 with 2, will you? Both of them are `Integer`s.  With the exactly same reason you don't need to distinguish `10**100` with 1.